# set values in property file using spring

Tags: java, spring, properties

Can anybody advise me how correctly work with *.propeties file in java using spring framework. 
There I have no any problems to read file:

```
@Component
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:/props.properties"})
public class UserParamsImpl{
  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  public void readProp(){
    String path = env.getRequiredProperty("folder.path");
  }

  public void setProp(String name, String val){
   //????????????????
  }

}
```

And one more question. Where I should hold props.properties ? Now it is in src/main/resources Is it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property file should be kept under src directory. and remove "/" from annotation.
Eg. suppose `pro.properties` is property file at `src/properties/props.properties.`

```
database.driverClassName=jdbc.odbc.mysql
database.user=sa
database.password=root@123
```

your java class should be

```
    @Component
    @PropertySource(value = {"classpath:properties/props.properties"})
    public class UserParamsImpl{
      @Autowired
      private Environment env;
      @Value("${database.driverClassName}")
      String dbName;

      public void readProp(){
            System.out.println("dbName");
      }

      public void setProp(String name, String val){
       //????????????????
      }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Mitesh. But your code dont solve all promblems. It let to load value from file. And how to set new property value in file?

Comment: thanks Vadim. If you want to add more values in property file just add new line item in key value fashion. You can make this post as Answer

Comment: Mitesh, do you know how to change item value in property file? Or maybe better to use xml file to store user settings?